# Embed subplot in cartopy map

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I want to embed subplots canvas inside a cartopy projected map. I wrote this code to show the expected result by using rectangles:

```
#%%
import numpy as np
import cartopy as cr
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from cartopy.io import shapereader
import geopandas

resolution = '10m'
category = 'cultural'
name = 'admin_0_countries'
shpfilename = shapereader.natural_earth(resolution, category, name)
# read the shapefile using geopandas
df = geopandas.read_file(shpfilename)
# read the country borders
usa = df.loc[df['ADMIN'] == 'United States of America']['geometry'].values[0]
can = df.loc[df['ADMIN'] == 'Canada']['geometry'].values[0]
central_lon, central_lat = -80, 60
extent = [-85, -55, 40, 62]
# ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Orthographic(central_lon, central_lat))

#Golden ratio
phi = 1.618033987
h = 7
w = phi*h

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(w,h))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
#Set map extent
ax.set_extent(extent)
ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(extent[0],extent[1],11))
ax.set_yticks(np.linspace(extent[2],extent[3],6))
ax.add_geometries(usa, crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), facecolor='none', 
                  edgecolor='k')
# ax.gridlines()

ax.coastlines(resolution='50m')


nx, ny = 7,6

#Begin firts rectangle
xi = extent[0] + 0.5
yi = extent[2] + 0.5

x, y = xi, yi
#Loop for create the plots grid
for i in range(nx):
    for j in range(ny):
        #Inner rect height
        in_h = 2.8
        #Draw the rect
        rect = ax.add_patch(mpatches.Rectangle(xy=[x, y], width=phi*in_h, height=in_h,
                                            facecolor='blue',
                                            alpha=0.2,
                                            transform=ccrs.PlateCarree()))
        #Get vertex of the drawn rectangle
        verts = rect.get_path().vertices
        trans = rect.get_patch_transform()
        points = trans.transform(verts)
        #Refresh rectangle coordinates
        x += (points[1,0]-points[0,0]) + 0.2
        if j == ny-1:
            x = xi
    y += (points[2,1]-points[1,1]) + 0.2
    
    
# print(points)

fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig('Figure.pdf',format='pdf',dpi=90)
plt.show()
```

This routine prints this figure
[image: Expected grid]

What I am looking for is a way to embed plots that match every single rectangle in the figure. I tried with `fig.add_axes`, but I couldn't get that mini-canvas match with the actual rectangles.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to embed the axes inside the parent axes is recommend using `inset_axes`, see the documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.inset_axes.html).

I wrote simple code to demonstrate how it works. Clearly there will be some tweaking of the inset_axes positions and sizes necessary for your desired output, but I think my trivial implementation already does decent.

All created axes instances are stored in a list so that they can be accessed later.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
axis = []
x = np.linspace(-85, -55)
y = np.linspace(40, 62)
ax.plot(x, y)

offset_l = 0.05
offset_h = 0.12
num_x = 6
num_y = 7
xs = np.linspace(offset_l, 1-offset_h, num_x)
ys = np.linspace(offset_l, 1-offset_h, num_y)

for k in range(num_x):
    for j in range(num_y):
        ax_ins = ax.inset_axes([xs[k], ys[j], 0.1, 0.1])
        ax_ins.axhspan(0, 1, color='tab:blue', alpha=0.2)
        axis.append(ax_ins)
```

[image: Output Figure]

Alternatively, you can also specify the inset_axes positions using data coordinates, for this you have to set the kwarg `transform` in the method to `transform=ax.transData`, see also my code below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#Golden ratio
phi = 1.618033987
h = 7
w = phi*h

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(w, h))
axis = []
x = np.linspace(-85, -55)
y = np.linspace(40, 62)
ax.plot(x, y)

offset_l = 0.05
offset_h = 0.12
num_x = 6
num_y = 7

fig.tight_layout()
extent = [-85, -55, 40, 62]
xi = extent[0] + 0.5
yi = extent[2] + 0.5
in_h = 2.8
in_w = phi * 2.8
spacing = 0.4

for k in range(num_x):
    for j in range(num_y):
        ax_ins = ax.inset_axes([xi+k*(in_w + phi*spacing), yi+j*(in_h + spacing),
                                in_w, in_h], transform=ax.transData)
        ax_ins.axhspan(0, 1, color='tab:blue', alpha=0.2)
        axis.append(ax_ins)
```

Comment: Seems to be a good first approach. However, how can I take the x,y coordinates of the big canvas to define the mini-plots extend and height, and width? In that way, they could match with the showed rectangles

Comment: This is also possible, see the documentation of `inset_axes`. I have extended my answer to your specific example.